# Syncfusion SfDataManager - Get loaded data

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, syncfusion-blazor

Can anybody show me an example, how it is possible to retrieve remote data via SfDataManager. I'm receiving the data, but I want to do some minor modifications to it before displaying it in a grid. Currently the data is displayed as it comes directly from the API. But I cannot find any property which allows me to access the received rows.